# sshfs to mount ftp folder to local folder not working

Tags: ssh, debian, mount, ftp, sshfs

in my debian I am trying to mount a remote FTP folder to a local folder with sshfs.
This is the command I use:

```
sshfs ftp_user@ftp_ip: /mnt/myfolder
```

The command is executed and I get the error:

```
read: connection reset by peer
```

What I tried is:

- adding my user to "fuse" group;
- uncomment "user_allow_other" in "/etc/fuse.conf" file
- giving the ownership of "myfolder" directory to the user
- restart

Comment: ftp is *not* ssh.

Comment: I know that, I thought sshfs worked with ftp either

Comment: But why??? ftp and ssh are *totally different* protocols.
https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 3):

For the FTP protocol, you should use **curlftpfs**:

```
# Install curlftpfs on Debian:
apt-get install curlftpfs

# Create a folder to mount in:
mkdir /mnt/myfolder

# Mount - exchange username, password and example.com:
curlftpfs -o allow_other,user=username:password example.com /mnt/myfolder/
```

Comment: But it's almost 20 years old (2008) and it has performance issue and "error while copying No such file or directory" ((( is there an alternative?